# PHP - live stream with XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

Is it possible to stream your desktop live with PHP and XAMPP. I have already tried
streaming one of my vidoes from my computer to an android phone, but is it possible   to stream my desktop and watch it from my android phone?

Comment: without cable or WiFi you can not steam data

Comment: @TarangP I'm using wireless connection

Comment: than its not possible.you may use your pc hotspot for that

Comment: @TarangP ok sir then, is it posible?

Comment: no.you should have to upload to live server.

Comment: @TarangP ok thanks